# When is a feature map continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

Let (X,$\tau$) be a Topological space (V,A,$d \nu$) a measure space. 
We have a function $\varphi: X \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ and we define the kernel $k:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ by $k(x,y)= \int_V \varphi(x,v) \varphi(y,v) d\nu (v)$. 
The questions now is: What properties should $\varphi$ satisfy such that the kernel $k$ is continuous? 
What I figured so far was:
It is enough to prove that the feature map is continuous. The feature space being $L^2(d\nu)$ and the feature map being $\Phi: X \to L^2(d\nu)$ such that $\Phi(x)=\varphi(x,\cdot)$. 
Also if $\varphi$ is continuous and we have a $g\in L^2(d\nu)$ such that $\forall x \in X$ $ || \varphi(x,\cdot) ||_{L^2(d\nu)} \leq || g ||_{L^2(d\nu)}$. I tried to prove it with sequence continuity and used the theorem of dominated convergence. The problem is this only works if $(X,\tau)$ has a first countable neighborhood basis. If I try to extend the proof with a net. I cannot use the theorem of dominated convergence.

Comment: I don't see what you mean. If the feature map is continuous and $(x_0,y_0)\in X^2$ is fixed, then $|k(x,y)-k(x_0,y_0)|\le\|\Phi(x)\|\|\Phi(y)-\Phi(y_0)\| + \|\Phi(y_0)\|\|\Phi(x)-\Phi(x_0)\|$, which implies continuity of $k$ at $(x_0,y_0)$, no matter what kind of space $X$ is.

Comment: Yes, this implies the continuity of $k$ if $\Phi$ is contiuous. Therefore I have to prove the continuity of $\Phi$.

Comment: Aww, and you ask for conditions on $\varphi$ such that $\Phi$ is continuous, I see. And you proved that $\Phi$ is continuous if $\varphi$ is and you have that neighborhood basis?

Comment: Yes this is what I tried one could also use another condition that implies that $k$ is continuous. Like $k(x,\cdot)$  and $x \mapsto k(x,x)$ being continuous but I don't see how that one helps. Or try to prove it directly but I always end up with the problem that I cannot swap the integral and limes.